# Strange error withQGeoPositionInfoSource from Android

Tags: android, qt, gps

I write a application in QTCreator for Android. I have a problem with my location from gps.
When I run application in my phone I didn't coordinate. In `qDebug` I see this:

> (void gps::startLocationAPI()): QGeoPositionInfoSourceAndroid(0x9f8c06d0)

What is bracket don't have a importance because every time this value is different (0xb03c9ba0, 0xb03d2ba0, 0xf01c9d10)

this is my code:

gps.h:

```
#ifndef GPS_H
#define GPS_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGeoPositionInfo>
#include <QGeoPositionInfoSource>
class gps : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit gps(QWidget *parent = 0);
    virtual ~gps();
public slots:
    void positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo geoPositionInfo);
    void startLocationAPI();
private:
     QGeoPositionInfoSource *m_pLocationInfo;
};
#endif //GPS_H
```

gps.cpp

```
#include "gps.h"

#include <QGeoCoordinate>
#include <QGeoPositionInfo>
#include <QGeoPositionInfoSource>
#include <QDebug>

gps::gps(QWidget *parent)
 : QObject(parent), m_pLocationInfo(NULL)
{
    startLocationAPI();
}

gps::~gps()
{
}

void gps::startLocationAPI()
{
    if (!m_pLocationInfo)
    {
        m_pLocationInfo =QGeoPositionInfoSource::createDefaultSource(0);
        m_pLocationInfo->setPreferredPositioningMethods(QGeoPositionInfoSource::NonSatellitePositioningMethods);
        connect(m_pLocationInfo, SIGNAL (positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)),this, SLOT (positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)));
        m_pLocationInfo->startUpdates();
        qDebug() << m_pLocationInfo;
    }
}

void gps::positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo geoPositionInfo)
{
}
```

Comment: Is `gps::positionUpdated` being called? Have you tried to put `qDebug() << "Hello"` in there to see if it gets called?

Answer (score 0):

If you output `m_pLocationInfo` it will always output different adresses as this is a pointer and its address most likely changes every time you run the program.

If you do:

```
void gps::positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo geoPositionInfo)
{
    qDebug() << geoPositionInfo.coordinate().toString();
}
```

Then you should get gps coordinates.

You may want to connect the `error` signal to know if something went wrong:

In `gps::startLocationAPI()`, add

```
connect(m_pLocationInfo, SIGNAL (error(QGeoPositionInfoSource::Error )),this, SLOT (error(QGeoPositionInfoSource::Error)));
```

and make `error(QGeoPositionInfoSource::Error)` be a slot of your gps class:

```
void gps::error(QGeoPositionInfoSource::Error positioningError)
{
    qDebug() << "An error occured: " << positioningError;
}
```

Then you'll know if something went wrong.